# Divide and conquer algorithm for making change with limited coins

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

The algorithm is supposed to find the number of ways change can be made for an input amount using only dimes, nickels, and pennies. My approach was to use a divide and conquer strategy and split the problem by finding the number of ways change can be made with the biggest coin, a dime, and the number of ways to make change without using a dime. I have written an implementation for this algorithm that solves the problem correctly for inputs from 1...14 but when the input is equal to or larger than 15 the returned result is incorrect. Obviously my algorithm is wrong and was wondering what changes need to be made to fix the code and if my approach is a proper divide and conquer solution.

The code is as follows:

```
    public static int makeChange(int n) {

        if(n < 0)
            return 0;
        else  {

        int sum = makeChange(n-10) + makeChange(n-5) + 1;

        return sum;
     }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What does `makeChange2` look like? Post it too.

Comment: Dynamic programming is more suited to this problem than divide and conquer.

Comment: *"when the input is equal to or larger than 15 the returned result is incorrect."*   What result did you get?  What result did you expect?  (or are you just going to leave us with "incorrect"??).  I also point out that you don't *actually ask a question* anywhere in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

```
int nways_10 (int n) {
    int s = 0;
    int d = n / 10;

    for (int i = 0; i <= d; ++i) {
        s += nways_5 (n - 10*i);
    }

    return s;
}
```

You should get the idea how to write `nways_5` and other functions, if needed.

Comment: Just to explain what is going on here: for each possible number of dimes you could use, find the number of ways to make change for what is left WITHOUT using any dimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get basic algorithm from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440228/creating-a-function-that-returns-combinations-of-change/19440582#19440582

you will need to modify it instead of output you should return 1, and summarize all ones to display count